# comma separated values of specific column in table to list of integers in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, split

I have one column with values 12,13,14 and I want that to be comma split and stored in list of integers `List<int>`. How can I do that?

```
 List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
 list1 = Array.ConvertAll(
     (
         from rar in unitOfWork.StudentRepository.GetAsQueryable()
         where rar.RequesterId == userId && rar.StatusId == 0
         select new { rar.RoleIds }
     )
 .AsEnumerable()
 .Select(r => string.Join(",", r.RoleIds))
 .ToArray(), int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.Split` and `SelectMany` are probably the pieces you're missing.

```
List<int> list1 =
     (
         from rar in unitOfWork.StudentRepository.GetAsQueryable()
         where rar.RequesterId == userId && rar.StatusId == 0
         select new { rar.RoleIds }
     )
    .AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(r => r.RoleIds.Split(','))
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting error as an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional statements in line r.RoleIds.split

Comment: @RushabhVora: Yeah, `Split` can't be done in SQL Server. Go ahead and add back in that `AsEnumerable()` call. I've changed the answer accordingly.